# VM behind nat on Proxmox cannot reach port from internal network

Tags: smtp, nat, port-forwarding, proxmox, ubuntu-22.04

The issue is that I am able to reach port 25 from outside (public internet) to the specific machine in the local network behind NAT, but cannot reach to port 25 on public machine e.g.  `hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.51.225]:25` from the local machine.

The network diagram is as the following:

[image]

From Proxmox server to OPNsense router is a rule for maquerade

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o enp0s31f6 -j MASQUERADE
```

Have created port forwarding with `iptables` from Proxmox server to OPNSense Router via ->

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.10:25
```

and also from OPNSense Router to the local machine via web interface.
It is working OK when i am trying to telnet into port 25 from outside of the network and the packets are forwarded to the correct machine and also can receive emails correctly via other ports.

But when trying to telnet from local machine to another public smtp server on port 25 cannot connect with timeout...

Outgoing connections on port 25 are also allowed since I can telnet on port 25 to a public service directly from Proxmox server, but not from local machine behind OPNSense (NAT)...

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but the solution is to provide an interface (-i) to the PREROUTING rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s31f6 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.10:25
```

In that way it works. Can someone explain it better why it works in this way and it doesn't work when not providing (-i) the the rule?